# add extra info box to wordpress post. plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a plugin of some sort or code of some sort to add in an extra box to the wordpress "add new post section"? I want to be able to have a product im selling on my wordpress page, and I want an extra "content box" that I can put in a description for the product. And pull in this description using shortcodes or something.

For example, If i have.

[image]

Is there a plugin that adds in a extra content box that I can pull the content from in my wordpress loop?

basically something like this, where the green box is a second content box where the content is not visible unless i use a shortcode for it in my loop.

[image]

Something like.

Wordpress loop... code code.....

```
<?php extra_product_info(); ?>
```

End loop...

and that would add in the text from 2nd content box.

Hope this makes sense or if anyone can steer me in the right direction

Comment: Use the Custom Field Suite plugin. http://customfieldsuite.com/ It will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: use advance custom fields plugins

Comment: Is there an advantage to one over the other?